# What is Metal Gear Solid 5 still downloading?

Tags: ps4, metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

So i picked up *Metal Gear Solid V: The Phantom Pain* from my Playstation+ Subscription and started downloading it. while i was playing *Final Fantasy XII* i got a pop up saying that Metal Gear was ready to be played.

I went to my download list to unpause Taletell's Borderland's (i put all the part on pause to prioritize Metal Gear) and saw that it's still downloading, but unlike what i normally see with downloads on my PS4 the progress bar is broken into 2 and the left smaller bar is full.

Now i do recall that *Metal Gear Solid V: The Phantom Pain* has this online base attack mode and assumed it might have been that but looking at the DLC available for the game i find almost everything that isn't a Premium Currency Top Up is for *Metal Gear Online* which makes me think that it could be downloading that

So i would like to know what is it that is being downloaded and can i cancel it and play all aspects of the single player for *Metal Gear Solid V: The Phantom Pain* without it wanting to be downloaded?

Comment: I remember reading somewhere (can't remember where) that some PS4 games work by first downloading just enough stuff to run the game and the first couple levels, and then downloads all the rest. That way you can start playing sooner then if you had to wait for the whole thing to download

Comment: Many PS4 games are split into 2 downloadable parts, so people can start playing after only part of the game has downloaded. It's possible you've downloaded the prologue and now the rest of the game is downloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have already mentioned, you can begin playing a downloaded title once a certain chunk has downloaded. Typically, this will be the first "stage" of the single player game. This feature has been around for a while, possibly since launch but I believe the UI change is newer.

Here's a [Reddit post on the Play As You Download fetaure](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/2mh76o/better_understanding_of_play_as_you_download/).

EDIT: From memory, the playable section of MGSV is limited to the prologue.